# Connection to the UCCX Database (Informix) via Python

Tags: python, odbc, pyodbc, informix

I'd like to pull out data from the Cisco UCCX database (Informix) with a Python script.

After installing the Informix Client SDK and `pyodbc` as described in [this guide](https://github.com/netvoip/uccx-stats/blob/master/doc/ODBC_guide.md), I run the following connection:

```
pyodbc.connect('SERVICE=1504;PROTOCOL=onsoctcp;CLIENT_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8;DB_LOCALE=en_US.UTF8;DRIVER={IBM INFORMIX ODBC DRIVER (64-bit)};UID=uccxhruser;PWD=my_pwd;DATABASE=db_cra;HOST=my-uccx;SERVER=my-uccx_uccx')
```

But I get the following error:

> Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [Informix][Informix ODBC
>   Driver][Informix]INFORMIXSERVER does not match either DBSERVERNAME or
>   DBSERVERALIASES. (-761) (SQLDriverConnect)')

How can I fix this?

Comment: On the face of it, you've set the environment variable `$INFORMIXSERVER` (or specified its value in the connection string) to an incorrect value.  Server names should not include dashes, so it might be that `SERVER=my-uccx_uccx` in the connection string is faulty, or it may be somewhere else.  I'd hazard a guess that your server is `my_uccx_uccx` instead — but that's a guess.  Knowing what is specified for the actual server will be crucial.

Comment: Ok I'll check this out, does the variable `INFORMIXSERVER` correspond to the `SERVER` param in the connection string?

Comment: That is information I don't have — there's a decent chance that SERVER in the connection string matches INFORMIXSERVER as an environment variable, but I don't know for sure.

Comment: According to the guide I posted in the question, there's no need to set `INFORMIXSERVER` explicitly. Maybe things are like your guess. I'll try to verify the UCCX/Informix server name.

Comment: Whooooaaaa! Turned out that the server name was `my_uccx_uccx` instead of `my-uccx_uccx` and now it works. If you turn your comment into an answer, I'd be happy to accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sup>*Converting comments into an answer.*</sup>

On the face of it, you've set the environment variable `$INFORMIXSERVER` (or specified its value in the connection string) to an incorrect value. Server names should not include dashes, so it might be that `SERVER=my-uccx_uccx` in the connection string is faulty, or it may be somewhere else. I'd hazard a guess that your server is `my_uccx_uccx` (an underscore instead of a dash) instead — but that's a guess. Knowing what is specified for the actual server will be crucial.

> Does the variable INFORMIXSERVER correspond to the SERVER param in the connection string?

That is information I don't have — there's a decent chance that `SERVER` in the connection string matches `INFORMIXSERVER` as an environment variable, but I don't know for sure.

*Given the later success, it is probable that `SERVER` in the connection string corresponds to `INFORMIXSERVER` in the environment.*

> Whooooaaaa! Turned out that the server name was `my_uccx_uccx` instead of `my-uccx_uccx` and now it works.

Great — I'm glad you're up and running.